# Android ::Close all activity in Tabhost when changeConfig

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

I try simple Tab application from [here](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html#comment-form)

I have simple problem, I run above application on an emulator as well as device, I have five activities (such as: A , B , C, D, E). I wanna go to A->B->C->D->E, after going E activity I change config using press key ctrl+ F11 on keyboard. When the change of orientation happens all activities are closed present in tab and showed the first activity.
I can't understand where I'm wrong..

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest file simply add this property in your all activities or in main activity.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: Thanks for replay,I m trying above but no result found.

Comment: Thanks **RobinHood** i forget in main activity. Thank you very much